# Uso de QUndoStack con varios widgets

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Imaginemos un Widget con sendos botones de *Undo* y de *Redo* y dos `QTextEdit`, llamados *Editor1* y *Editor2*

Sabemos que cada `QTextEdit` tiene su método `undo()` y `redo()` Hasta ahora todo lo que veo, y soy capaz de hacer, es que cuando pulso a los botones *Undo* y *Redo* llamo al método `undo()` y `redo()` del editor activo en ese momento y ejecuto la secuencia de comandos a hacer o deshacer.

Pero lo que me gustaría es tener la pila `QUndoStack` que almacenara cada cambio de cada `QTextEdit` de forma que si por ejemplo modifico un texto en *Editor1*, luego cambio a *Editor2* y efectúo modificaciones, y vuelvo a pasar al primero, cuando pulse el botón de *Undo* no me llame al método `undo()` del editor activo (*Editor1*) sino que deshaga la última acción ejecutada, la cual fue realizada en el *Editor2*.

Se me ocurren dos formas:
**1.-** Redefinir todas y cada una de las acciones que haría cada editor (escribir, borrar, formatear...) para que pasen por la pila `QUndoStack` del widget principal. Lo veo muy largo y tedioso.
**2.-** Intentar que cada vez que una acción de cada `QTextEdit`pase a su pila particular de alguna manera pueda pasar a la pila del widget principal, lo cual no sé si es factible.

Pero no sé si hay otra forma mejor y en todo caso, al menos, cómo se haría lo expuesto en el punto 2

La pregunta más cercana a la mía es esta, pero no está respondida:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998836/implementing-undo-redo-functionality-in-qt/14999016#14999016

Comment: Hola User, y cual es tu pregunta?

Comment: Pues saber si es factible lo que digo en el punto 2. Es decir, que pueda capturar de alguna forma las acciones guardadas en las pilas de cada QTextEdit para crear una pila undo/redo "general" y si no es posible, cual sería la mejor forma de implementar esa pila. (es que no creo que sea muy lógico tener que definir cada acción que haga en el editor para que pase por la pila, como digo en el punto 1)

Comment: Esta es la pregunta más cercana a la mía, pero no está respondida: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998836/implementing-undo-redo-functionality-in-qt/14999016#14999016